# Multiprocessing pool doesn't seem to even call function?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I am trying to call a function in parallel using multiprocessing. I have used both starmap and map many times in the past to do so, but suddenly multiprocessing has stopped working. A pool is created, but the function is never called and the cell never finishes running. To test the issue, I am running a simple example code:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def f(x):
    print(x)
    return x*x

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = Pool(1)
    results = p.map(f, [1, 2, 3])
    p.close()
    p.join()
```

When I run this, nothing is printed, and the process never completes.
I have also tried running old code from previous notebooks that contain multiprocessing, and these have failed, too. I tried updating all packages as well. Has anyone else experienced this problem before?

Comment: Can you reproduce this without IPython Notebook?

Comment: Also, which specific IPython Notebook kernel version are you using?

Comment: BTW, I can reproduce a failure running this code with Python 3.8, but not with Python 2.7. (It's not a silent failure, though -- very much does throw an exception; and if you _are_ getting exceptions, they need to be included in the question).

Comment: Anyhow -- if it _is_ what I think it is, you can find relevant documentation at https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/10894. The piece of the documentation quoted there is important: *Functionality within this package requires that the `__main__` module be importable by the children. This is covered in* Programming guidelines *however it is worth pointing out here. This means that some examples, such as the `multiprocessing.pool.Pool` examples will not work in the interactive interpreter.*

Comment: I am not getting an exceptions or seemingly any response from the cell block at all. When I run the code, my Activity Monitor doesn't even indicate that Jupyter is using any CPU, as if I'm not running anything. I am using Notebook 6.1.6.

Comment: If it is the issue mentioned above, how do I go about remedying it?

Comment: The easiest approach is to save your code in a Python module rather than trying to embed it directly in a notebook cell.